# Why does chrono have its own namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

Everything else I have seen so far in the C++ standard library is in the `std` namespace. If I use things from `std::chrono` I usually exceed my 80 character per line limit - that is not a problem, just inconvienent.

So here my simple question: Why does the chrono header has its own namespace?

Comment: Ditch the 80 character limit, this isn't the 80s anymore.

Comment: I actually introduced the limit for myself after not using one before. If you open a debugger to your left on a laptop with a limited screen width it is fairly useful. Also in the rare case when you print out your code. In general, I think code that does not fit into a single 80-character line is less readable, see for example some of Java's library interfaces ;)

Comment: You'll be much better off if you deal with it on a case-by-case basis. If fitting the line into 80 characters forces you  to introduce awkward breaks, don't do it. If breaking a line at character 23 makes it easier to read, do it. There's no single number.

Comment: Or just, you know, `namespace sc = std::chrono;`

Comment: Since it's now the 2010's, the new limit is 2010-1900 = 110 characters per line ;)

Comment: [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Line_Length) reads: "Each line of text in your code should be at most 80 characters long."

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I was lead author on the [chrono proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2661.htm).  A sub-namespace was not my first choice, just because of the verbosity.  I find myself writing `using namespace std::chrono` almost every time I use the facility.

However this was a very controversial proposal.  And many people, including some of my co-authors strongly felt that a sub-namespace was appropriate.  I did not strongly object to the sub-namespace because we were in a space of needing to compromise, or become just as dead-locked as the US congress. :⁠-⁠)  The result of such a dead-lock would have probably been C11's `timespec`.

boost has experimented with sub-namespaces much more aggressively than the std has and one of the key authors on this paper is also the author of the boost date-time library upon which chrono evolved from.  So that would obviously have a strong pull in the direction of using a sub-namespace.

Looking forward it is quite possible that the sub-namespace will become absolutely required.  Imagine if we add calendrical services that include an abbreviation for December: `dec`.  This would directly conflict with:

```
ios_base& dec(ios_base& str);
```

in `<ios>`.  So all in all, I was probably wrong in not insisting on a sub-namespace from the beginning. :⁠-⁠)  Going forward it will be interesting to watch where the committee does and does not create sub-namespaces.

**Update (6 years later...)**

The truth is always stranger than fiction...

So I *did* propose `std::chrono::dec` as an abbreviation for `December`, thinking that would be safe because of the nested `chrono` namespace.  But no, the committee decided to rename `std::chrono::dec` to `std::chrono::December` during the standardization process because of potential conflicts.

So are nested namespaces worth it?

I don't know.  This update is a datapoint, not an opinion.

Comment: Will there be a push to move existing libraries in their own sub-namespaces for consistency, but also put them in `std` (for backwards compatibility)? General best practice is usually not to use `using namespace`. Will sub-namespaces under `std` change this, and is that a good thing? There are legitimate reasons not to use it, but `chrono` is too cumbersome without `using namespace std::chrono`.

Comment: @Dave:  The future is always hard to predict (especially when talking about what the committee will do), but I doubt the committee will retrofit sub-namespaces onto existing signatures.

Comment: @HowardHinnant, I've a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44269533/213871) regarding `time_point` and `duration` classes internal storage limitations

Comment: @HowardHinnant, just curious, but why was chrono a "very controversial proposal?"  (And thanks for helping to author it, by the way.)

Comment: @Dan.  A significant number of people on the committee wanted to standardize the POSIX `timespec` (a `struct` with a field for seconds and a field for nanoseconds).  This solution was simple, and had loads of field experience.  And it has C compatibility.  When [N2661](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2661.htm) was written, that was the  audience I was writing for.  When contrasted with vastly more complicated `<chrono>` specification, it was not an easy sell.  I tried to emphasize that the _user's_ experience would be simpler and less error prone.

Comment: @HowardHinnant, that's interesting.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 7):

There are other namespaces too, like `std::placeholders`. Ultimately, in C++03 the Committee did not go for subnamespaces, but it is now painfully obvious that the `std` namespace is becoming massively overloaded. As such, I expect that many library proposals for C++14 will use a subnamespace for larger organizations of components.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on "massively overloaded"? I mean, it is true that with C++11 the standard library is growing and along with that also the members in the `std` namespace. But I do not see a reason why putting e.g. `a` into `std::subnamespace` if there is no `a` in `std` yet.

Comment: Because then you end up with `std::a` and `std::sub::a`, instead of `std::sub1::a` and `std::sub2::a`. More importantly, there's simply a whole bunch of `a` already used.